Display issues in cells when splitting date/time into multiple columns
When using the =right formula to split the date and time so that just the time displays in a separate column, the values didn't always display correctly. First the values came into the new column as text, so I converted the values to a number. Then I selected the time format of hh:mm:ss. Still, only a few of the values appeared as expected while most of the cells displayed #####.
I tried using different time formats. I also changed the cells by removing the formula and using paste-special to only leave the values.  Still, most of the the cells still displayed ##### rather than the hh:mm:ss I was expecting.

Make the columns wider.
Excel displays ##### for date/time values if the column is not wide enough to show the selected format.

If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.
